# How to return multiple rows from PL/SQL procedure?

Tags: oracle, plsql

I have a scenario where I need to return multiple rows from a PL/SQL procedure. These rows are decided from multiple queries and few business logics. i.e. I cannot write a single query to fetch it to a cursor and return.

Is there any way to create local table variable within a procedure and insert into it and then fetch it to a cursor and return it. Or is there any better approach to solve this.?

This procedure is called from a Java method and the results should be returned as an OUT parameter to it.

Comment: Which version. You may use `dbms_sql.return_result` in 12c

Comment: Have a look at pipelined functions. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15767566/functions-pipelined

Comment: Associative Arrays. https://docs.oracle.com/cloud/latest/db112/LNPLS/composites.htm#LNPLS005

Comment: I have to return these results to java.

Comment: why don't you use result set .. based on pipelined function? Do you really need an out parameter?

Comment: This is a bad idea and almost certainly isn't going to work. The reason that it isn't going to work is that you can only call stored procedures returning `SQL`  rather than `PlSql` types (with some exceptions).  Change your SP to return either a `ResultSet` or a `SysRefcursor`.